# magento 2: understanding dependency injection

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

Recently I came across a situation in magento where settings for instance object were remaining persistent and it made we wonder how magento's di is working.

I created a module that injects magento's curl class `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl`

```
public function __construct
(
  \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl $curl
)
{
  $this->curl = $curl;
}

public function getGeoIpResponse($ip)
{
  $this->curl->setConfig(['header' => false]);
  $this->curl->write('GET', $ip);

  return $this->curl->read();
}
```

This provides back a json with no header, because of `['header' => false]`, prepended to the response.

Now in a separate class I inject the same curl class and run a similar method but DO NOT set the header to false.  However the response comes back with no header; the default config returns a header.  In order to receive a header i would have to set `['header' => true]` in the config.

```
public function __construct
(
  \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl $curl
)
{
  $this->curl = $curl;
}

public function getFixerResponse($base) {

  $this->curl->write('GET', $this->fixerUrl . $base);

  $response = $this->curl->read();

  return $response;
}
```

If I remove the first instance where `['header' => false]`, leaving the second instance unchanged, then the second instance's response returns a header.

I expected the instances to work independent of each other but it seems the config is shared between the two objects.

Can anyone explain why the configuration of the first instance is remaining persistent on the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a class is requested as a dependency for an other class Magento will first check in the DI container (DIC) for an instance of that class.
If it exists, it will return it, if not it will create the instance, add it to the DIC and return it to be injected in the class that requires it.
This means that all dependencies act as singletons.
In you case, if you need a different instance of the `Curl` class you can just inject a `CurlFactory` instance instead of the `Curl` instance.
Something like this:

First class

```
public function __construct
(
  \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\CurlFactory $curlFactory //don't worry, the Factory class will be autogenerated
)
{
  $this->curl = $curlFactory->create();
}

public function getGeoIpResponse($ip)
{
  $this->curl->setConfig(['header' => false]);
  $this->curl->write('GET', $ip);

  return $this->curl->read();
}
```

Second class

```
public function __construct
(
  \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\CurlFactory $curlFactory //don't worry, the factory class will be auto generated
)
{
  $this->curl = $curlFactory->create();
}

public function getFixerResponse($base) {

  $this->curl->write('GET', $this->fixerUrl . $base);

  $response = $this->curl->read();

  return $response;
}
```

Comment: In this case CurlFactory already exists.  After using CurlFactory, instances worked independently.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the object instance is shared. If you request the same object many times in different classes you will get the same instance.

See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html#object-manager-overview#object-lifestyle-management for more details

Answer (score 0):

It is about prototype vs singleton scope.

In magento2, by default, the object instance is unique (shared) during the container's lifecycle - each injection returns the same instance (**singleton scope**).

To change it to a prototype scope, change your di.xml file and use `shared="false"`:

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <type name="Model/Example" **shared="false"**>
        <!-- ... arguments/argument tags here if you want to change injected arguments -->
    </type>
</config>
```

If shared is set to false, then Magento2 will use the create method to instantiate an object every time it sees your class (instead of the default get method)

http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_instance_objects

Answer (score 0):

Earlier, I had the same issue with my code.Magento 2 class has some limitation that we can not use more  than 13 instances of another class within your class body.
You can use less than 13 instances or create another class and define the maximum object in that call and use new class (has initialised objects) into your class.