# Dependency Injection? Do not understand it, can anyone help?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I started to use Magento 2.x and noticed that the Mage "API" is no longer a reality, and red about **dependency injection** and **factory** but I did not understand what it is, what it does or where I write its code (path).

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the object instance is shared. If you request the same object many times in different classes you will get the same instance.

[magento 2: understanding dependency injection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123024/magento-2-understanding-dependency-injection)

[Factory Class vs. Proxy Class in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104522/factory-class-vs-proxy-class-in-magento2)

You can read from here magento officially site.

**Read more about Factories**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/factories.html

**Read more about Dependecy injection**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html

Comment: You have to add code in module block.